# Parent element paddings don't produce scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, padding

I have simple HTML, blue box within yellow one with scrollbar:

```css
.outer {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: yellow;
} 
.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The issue relates to outer box paddings and the difference between scrollbar appearance in Chrome (v81) and Firefox (v75).

- Chrome shows inner container as 100px blue box surrounded by 50px yellow paddings (with scrollbar)
- Firefox also shows 100px blue box, but only top yellow 50px padding is present (with no scrollbar)

Is my code improper from the standpoint of HTML/CSS specifications? or is it a browser issue? which browser is wrong? My guess is that the inner box height should be added to the outer box height with no taking outer paddings into account; bottom padding should not be absorbed (Chrome way). If it's not true, how it can be achieved in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

So there really isn't a browser issue at all, but your boxes are missing the box sizing property. If you add box-sizing: border-box to your outer div it will make the browsers consistent with each other.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not about box-sizing -- https://jsfiddle.net/dhilt/3gv6doc5/18/ -- despite the slight difference in the layout (e.g we see a scrollbar), the same issue is still here: Firefox consumes bottom padding and the cumulative height in FF is less than in Chrome

Comment: So opening your fiddle in both FF and Chrome I see the same exact result. They both scroll.

Comment: I noticed scroll appearance in my comment, as also I noticed the inconsistence between cumulative height in FF and Chrome. Do you see the same heights in both environments on your end?

Comment: Yep both chrome and ff are saying 617x150 which is how wide the area rendering the code is.

Comment: Btw, here's the proof of FF bug related to my issue (thanks to @temani-afif): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748518

Comment: Huh that is pretty interesting that the bug came back seemed like it was fixed ages ago.